# How to import CSV to potsgresql table if not superuser

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm trying to copy csv file to postgresql table. As far as I am not superuser (and cannot get superuser password) I cannot do this, unless I use stdout or stdin. But here is a little problem, I don't know how to do this either.
Also, I read that file must be accessible to database server, but I don't know how to make file accessible to database server either.

Answer (score 2):

Use `psql`'s `\copy`, not `COPY`.

PgAdmin-III has the equivalent "import" option for a table.

See the many (many) related questions here on SO for details.